# On Shortening Code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm quite new to programming in Python. I have always written my `int` inputs like the following example to ensure a user inputs an `int`. This is a specific example I have in my code that I'm sure I can shorten and thus learn for future projects.

This ensures a three digit number is input by creating a loop that breaks when a three digit number is entered.

```
while 1 == 1:
  print("Input a 3 digit number")
    #The try statement ensures an INTEGER is entered by the user
    try:
      x = int(input())
      if 100 <= x < 1000:
        break
      else:
        print()
    except ValueError:
      print()
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: BTW, check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Your question would be much more acceptable there.

Comment: `while 1 == 1:` is more idiomatically written as `while True:`

Comment: The first print statement can be absorbed as an argument to `input`

Comment: @Chris I have tried to input 100.3 and it doesn’t not pass.

Comment: @Mad I will check it out thanks for the insight as well, I did not know while True: is a statement that is useable thank you.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Performing `int` on a floating-point number will throw a `ValueError` exception, which the code currently handles.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
while True:
    x = input("Input a 3 digit number: ")
    if x.isdigit() and 100 <= int(x) <= 999:
        break
```

`isdigit()` checks whether the string consists of digits only (won't work for floats). Since Python uses short-circuiting to evaluate boolean expressions using the operator `and`, the second expression `100 <= int(x) <= 999` will not be evaluated unless the first (`x.isdigit()`) is true, so this will not throw an error when a string is provided. If `isdigit()` evaluates to False, the second expression won't be evaluated anyway.

Another option is the following:

```
condition = True
while condition:
    x = input("Input a 3 digit number: ")
    condition = not (x.isdigit() and 100 <= int(x) <= 999)
```

Comment: "003".isdigit() is True and I think you want if x.isdigit() and 100 <= int(x) < 1000:

Comment: Good catch! Thanks, I will fix it

Comment: The original method allows something like `0x45`. This might be an improvement for that reason as well.

Comment: Thank you for the help this is what’s I was looking for. It’s always nice to improve your coding skills and I knew there had to be a more efficient way.

Comment: @Webber If this answer or any other answer have solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the “tick” icon. It helps to keep stackoverflow organised.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to handle the two different failures separately (not an int vs not 3 digit) you could do something like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input('enter a 3 digit number'))
        assert(100 <= x <= 999)
    except ValueError: print('not an int')
    except AssertionError: print('int not 3 digit')
    else: break
```

It's not worlds shorter, but it is still very readable, and gives extra information to the user. Additionally if your intent is to make it re-usable, you should make it a function (just replace `break` with `return x` and add `def funcname():` to the beginning (don't forget indentation)).

Comment: Nice solution Aaron!

Comment: I should like to point out that using `assert` is generally only for debug purposes (assert statements are stripped out with `python -o`), but I wanted an easy way to generate a separate `Exception` type to show the usage of multiple `except:` blocks for a single `try:`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fun alternative that avoids the need for a break or an exception at all:

```
x = ""
while not x.isdigit() or (100 > int(x) or int(x) > 999):
    x = input("Input a 3 digit number")
x = int(x)
```